# rails model validation error on view does not render properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i am using a status radio_button field on form, and when i add `validate :status, presence: true` error message on form doesn't render properly it makes form view weired. Is there any solution i can render status error better?

i have added screenshot look at status field it was inline but after error i get status field in open upon other.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="field columns large-6">
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <span>
    <%= form.radio_button :status, "1"  %>
    <%= form.label :completed %>
    </span>
    <span>
    <%= form.radio_button :status, "0"  %>
    <%= form.label :inprogess %>
    </span>
    <span>
    <%= form.radio_button :status, "2"  %>
    <%= form.label :yet_to_start %>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="field columns large-6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `error message on form doesn't render properly it makes form view weird` what does by that means? In case you want a better view you can make some cosmetic changes by adding some CSS.

Comment: Please add more details, not enough details are provided for any helpful answer

Comment: Thanks for the updates to question, this seems to me more of css issue, which can't be addressed with provided info, basically you need to dig in and find css which si causing this and where it is coming from and than work around that. Sorry.

Comment: BTW it seems error is being appended to all radio buttons, while you want the error to appear on label or the group, not individually on all fields. There must be ways to achieve it depending on where you want your error message to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, add the following piece of code to your `application.rb` file

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| html_tag }
```

or you can try making the fields inline by adding this css

```
.fields_with_error{ display: inline }
```

It will stop wrapping fields with errors with divs and that might solve your problem. Worth giving a try.

Comment: What gives you impression that he don't want error indicators at all? I find the question very unclear to answer.

Comment: Looking at the form, that's the only thing that came to mind, let him try and check if the error wrappers were the culprit or not, if it works then he can go with this or think of a better solution, if not he will remove this anyway.

Comment: Well i think yes, the error wrappers might have been making UI weird, but that does not mean he want to get rid of error indicators in the UI, and also, we should not encourage removal of error indicators anyway. That was my point. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh i want wrapper but it should be inline. error wrappers also shrinks form field.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh CSS is not resolving problem issue is same.